# Error: bad 'S3method' directive: S3method(plot) in R

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am writing a R package using `devtools`. Now I have a generic function `plot` that can take different classes (e.g. `plot.fact`, `plot.numer`, etc.). In the `.R` file of `plot.fact`, I use `#'` comment for documentations in a roxygen way. Besides other items, I specify the following comments:

```
#' @rdname plot
#' @method plot fact
#' @S3method plot fact
#' @export
```

However, when I run `check('pkg')` the following error message appear: `Error: bad 'S3method' directive: S3method(plot)`. Is there anything wrong with how I write the comments? Or do I have to write a `plot <- function(x,...) UseMethod("plot")` before the function `plot.fact`? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

To be more precise, my `plot.fact` function does not have a single argument `x`; instead, it has many extra parameters to customize the plot. The arguments are

`plot.fact <- function(x, conf.env=0.95, data.note="", leg.cex=1, ...)`

According to Hadley's suggestion, I use

```
#' @rdname plot
#' @method plot fact
#' @export
```

But the error is still `bad 'S3method' directive`... Do I need to write down

```
plot <- function(x, conf.env=0.95, data.note="", leg.cex=1, ...) {
  UseMethod("plot")
}
```

before the definition of `plot.fact`? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your troubles, but the signature of the plot generic is `function (x, y, ...)`.  So your methods should all start with `x,y` rather than the `x` that you've got in your proposed generic.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman: yep! I updated my post above to make the question more clearly. Thanks!

Comment: The formal signature of a method must include all the terms (preferably in the same order) as the generic it extends.  So you need a `y` argument also, even if you then discard `y`.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman thank you so much for the help! My code finally works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to document the method use `@method plot fact` + `@export`.
- If you don't want to document it, use `@s3method plot fact`.

You shouldn't ever have `@method` and `@s3method` in the same block.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! I still got the same error as before, so please see the updated post above. Thanks!

Comment: Finally it works...thank you all for your help! I realize that I need to put `@export @method plot fact` in order. In that way, when I use the `check` function in `devtools`, the `NAMESPACE` file will add at the very beginning `S3method(plot, fact)`, which is desired ;)